# Flutter Firestore is feching old data

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

So all of a sudden, firestore is fetching old data. I Assume its caching it or something? Randomly started doing it today.

```
DocumentSnapshot testSnapshot =
    await collRef.document('j7VTRjlHiPd6W6x0x7IzFzi7BJq1').get();
```

[image]

That is stale data, as seen below

[image]

How on earth do I fix this, and why did this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted the record, and created a new record.

No idea, and no reason the data was cached. Hope this doesn't happen on prod.